# react router dom link with params dont allways work

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have written a simple search component with autosuggestion in react, it makes calls to the themoviedb. I am using react-router-dom and have defined a route param like this in app.js:

```
<Route path="/:id" component={SomeComponent} />
```

and the search component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";

const SuggestionsResult = styled.ul`
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
`;

const ResultItem = styled.li`
  border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.12);
  padding: 10px 0 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.12);
  }
`;

export default class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    results: [],
    showSuggestions: false
  };

  handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        query: this.search.value
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
          if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
            axios
              .get(
                `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&query=${
                  this.state.query
                }&page=1&include_adult=false`
              )
              .then(({ data }) => {
                this.setState({
                  results: data.results,
                  showSuggestions: !this.state.showSuggestions
                });
              });
          }
        } else if (!this.state.query) {
        }
      }
    );
  };



  handleSuggestionClick = e => {
    this.setState({ showSuggestions: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <input
          placeholder="Search for a movie..."
          ref={input => (this.search = input)}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        {this.state.showSuggestions && (
          <Suggestions
            results={this.state.results}
            handleSuggestionClick={this.handleSuggestionClick}
          />
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const Suggestions = ({ results, handleSuggestionClick }) => {
  const options = results.map(r => (
    <ResultItem key={r.id}>
      <Link onClick={handleSuggestionClick} to={`/${r.id}`}>
        {r.title}
      </Link>
    </ResultItem>
  ));
  return <SuggestionsResult>{options}</SuggestionsResult>;
};
```

**My problem is when clicking on the link it changes the url but it stays on the same site.** If I dont use react-router-dom Link component and only use a elements it works fine but everthing re-renders.

** Update
My react-router code in app.js

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={MoviesList} />
        <Route path="/:id" component={MovieDetail} />
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Please create a sandbox example. It will help us to debug fast thus you will get answers faster. :)

Comment: @KalpeshSingh I dont want share my API key, if you want try it out you can create free api at https://themoviedb.org.

Comment: @KalpeshSingh bounty for u =)

Comment: are you running this with CRA? it is important that you make server-side redirects to make all traffic go to / and let react-router do it's job

Comment: @DavidMunoz Yes, I am using CRA. I dont think I have any server side redirects.

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake CRA should take care of that, now, what does your react-router code looks like?

Comment: @DavidMunoz I updated my question with react-router code. The router component is BrowserRouter.

Comment: Hey @SHUMAcupcake, try this and let me know if this pattern makes thing working for you. https://codesandbox.io/s/3r3x9z81

If this works then I will provide detailed answer. ;)

Comment: @KalpeshSingh didnt work

Comment: I think a bare-minimum code is needed. Please create your codesandbox and fake data in it.

Answer (score 4):

The Suggestions component doesn't receive the Router prop and hence it causes this issue. Wrap your Suggestions component with `withRouter` HOC.  Also make sure that the Search component is rendered as a child or `Router` component

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";

const SuggestionsResult = styled.ul`
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
`;

const ResultItem = styled.li`
  border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.12);
  padding: 10px 0 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.12);
  }
`;

export default class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    results: [],
    showSuggestions: false
  };

  handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        query: this.search.value
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
          if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
            axios
              .get(
                `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&query=${
                  this.state.query
                }&page=1&include_adult=false`
              )
              .then(({ data }) => {
                this.setState({
                  results: data.results,
                  showSuggestions: !this.state.showSuggestions
                });
              });
          }
        } else if (!this.state.query) {
        }
      }
    );
  };



  handleSuggestionClick = e => {
    this.setState({ showSuggestions: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <input
          placeholder="Search for a movie..."
          ref={input => (this.search = input)}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        {this.state.showSuggestions && (
          <Suggestions
            results={this.state.results}
            handleSuggestionClick={this.handleSuggestionClick}
          />
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const Suggestions = withRouter(({ results, handleSuggestionClick }) => {
  const options = results.map(r => (
    <ResultItem key={r.id}>
      <Link onClick={handleSuggestionClick} to={`/${r.id}`}>
        {r.title}
      </Link>
    </ResultItem>
  ));
  return <SuggestionsResult>{options}</SuggestionsResult>;
});
```